# Enforce data integrity with a recursive table

Tags: oracle, database-design, oracle-11g-r2

I have an existing oracle 11g database schema that works with a web application. I am planning an expansion to the application so a web service can do data operations on the database.  As part of the planning I have realized that there are no data integrity checks on parent/child relationships which would make it problematic to let other applications work with the table. I am planning to do validation in the web service but the best practice is to have validation in the database and the web service.

```
--the base lookup table has a table with text values that is not shown.
--Example Red, Green, 
CREATE TABLE PROPERTY
(
  ID                        NUMBER(9)           NOT NULL, --PRIMARY KEY
  TENANT_ID                 NUMBER(9)           NOT NULL
)
-- a property may or may not have a parent property. 
--Example "Weight" of an item is a child of the "Shipping Weight"
CREATE TABLE PROPERTY_DEPENDENCY  --PRIMARY KEY PROPERTY_ID,PROPERTY_TYPE_ID
(
  PROPERTY_ID               NUMBER(9)           NOT NULL,
  PARENT_PROPERTY_ID        NUMBER(9),
  PROPERTY_TYPE_ID          NUMBER(9)           NOT NULL,
  ACTIVE                    NUMBER(1)           NOT NULL
)
--examples "Item Colour", "Item Trim Colour","Shipping Weight", "Weight"
CREATE TABLE PROPERTY_TYPE
(
  ID                        NUMBER(9)           NOT NULL,  --PRIMARY KEY
  VALUE                     VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)  NOT NULL,
  PROPERTY_TYPE             NUMBER(10)          DEFAULT 1   NOT NULL
)

--and the table that you insert and update into
CREATE TABLE CASE_PROPERTY
(
  ID                        NUMBER(9)           NOT NULL, --PRIMARY KEY
  PARENT_ID                 NUMBER(9),          --constraint on PROPERTY
  CASE_ID                   NUMBER(9)           NOT NULL,--foreign key
  PROPERTY_ID               NUMBER(9),          --constraint on PROPERTY
  PROPERTY_TYPE_ID          NUMBER(9)           NOT NULL --constraint on PROPERTY_TYPE
)
```

These are the problems I have identified:

- you can insert into CASE_PROPERTY and make a property it's own parent or grandparent
- you can insert the wrong PROPERTY_TYPE_ID for a PROPERTY_ID into CASE_PROPERTY
- you can insert into CASE_PROPERTY a PARENT_ID which makes no sense for a PROPERTY_TYPE_ID

I can add a check constraint so that `PARENT_ID <> PROPERTY_ID` so you cannot be a parent to yourself.

**Edit 3:**
The real problem is that the tables are not normalized properly which is great for reporting but hard on data validation. `CASE_PROPERTY.PROPERTY_TYPE_ID` should always be the same as the value in `PROPERTY_DEPENDENCY.PROPERTY_TYPE_ID` but I don't know how to validate this.

Are there any ways other than triggers to enforce data integrity on `CASE_PROPERTY`?

**Edit:** I'll put together a complete example. If I added foreign key constraints on `PROPERTY_DEPENDENCY` I would verify that only properties with parents were inserted but would they be the correct parents?

**Edit 2:** Here is a complete example of the inserts that are allowed.  The last two inserts are examples of data that is allowed but should not be.

```
ALTER TABLE CASE_PROPERTY ADD  CONSTRAINT CASE_PROPERTY_R01  FOREIGN
KEY (PARENT_ID)  REFERENCES CASE_PROPERTY (ID)  ENABLE  VALIDATE

Insert into PROPERTY    (ID, TENANT_ID)  Values    (2, 1); 
Insert into PROPERTY    (ID, TENANT_ID)  Values    (3, 1); 
Insert into PROPERTY    (ID, TENANT_ID)  Values    (4, 1); 

Insert into PROPERTY_TYPE    (ID, 
    VALUE, PROPERTY_TYPE)  Values    (10, 'Colour', 2);    
Insert into PROPERTY_TYPE    (ID, 
    VALUE, PROPERTY_TYPE)  Values    (11, 'Trim Colour', 1);    
Insert into PROPERTY_TYPE    (ID, 
    VALUE, PROPERTY_TYPE)  Values    (12, 'Shipping Weight', 1); 
Insert into PROPERTY_TYPE    (ID, 
    VALUE, PROPERTY_TYPE)  Values    (13, 'Weight', 3); 

Insert into PROPERTY_DEPENDENCY    (PROPERTY_ID, 
    PARENT_PROPERTY_ID, PROPERTY_TYPE_ID)  Values    (4, 3, 11); 
Insert into PROPERTY_DEPENDENCY    (PROPERTY_ID, 
    PARENT_PROPERTY_ID, PROPERTY_TYPE_ID)  Values    (3, NULL, 10);
Insert into PROPERTY_DEPENDENCY    (PROPERTY_ID, 
    PARENT_PROPERTY_ID, PROPERTY_TYPE_ID)  Values    (1, NULL, 12);    
Insert into PROPERTY_DEPENDENCY    (PROPERTY_ID, 
    PARENT_PROPERTY_ID, PROPERTY_TYPE_ID)  Values    (2, 1, 13); 

--example of a property validated data insert

--item 201 with type 13 is the child of item 200 of type 12
Insert into CASE_PROPERTY    (ID, 
    PARENT_ID, CASE_ID, PROPERTY_ID, PROPERTY_TYPE_ID)  Values    (200, NULL, 3000, 1, 12); 
Insert into CASE_PROPERTY    (ID, 
    PARENT_ID, CASE_ID, PROPERTY_ID, PROPERTY_TYPE_ID)  Values    (201, 200, 3000, 2, 13); 

--bad data inserts

-- a property is parent to itself with an incorrect property_type_id 

Insert into CASE_PROPERTY    (ID, 
    PARENT_ID, CASE_ID, PROPERTY_ID, PROPERTY_TYPE_ID)  Values    (202, 202, 4000, 3, 10);  
--should be 202, null,4000,3,10 

--a property is inserted with a parent that is not allowed 

Insert into CASE_PROPERTY    (ID, 
    PARENT_ID, CASE_ID, PROPERTY_ID, PROPERTY_TYPE_ID)  Values    (203, 200, 4000, 2, 13);  
--parent property should be 1 not 2
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your model, especially regarding PK and FK between the 3 first tables. You might want to add an example with some typical data. Anyway, why not have your `case_property` table reference `property_dependency`?

Comment: It's still cryptic, sorry. Anyway, I would strongly suggest [not using triggers, use procedures instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161064/abort-insert-update-operation-in-trigger-using-pl-sql/15161423#15161423). It is [not possible to implement multi-row integrity constraints in a multi-user environment with triggers](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:53473305799476).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not know if this will be useful to you because it requires quite a few changes, but the problem is interesting, so I'll try.

These would be the major changes

- Using the tree closure instead of the adjacency list for the reference hierarchy. The closure table contains paths form each parent to all of it descendants, so all possible parent-child combinations are exposed.

Note that with the tree closure, each ancestor node points to itself as a descendant, meaning that in `CaseProperty` recursion stops on `ID = ParentID` instead on `ParentID is NULL`

It is not clear to me is a parent allowed to be any ancestor or just the one first step up. The closure table exposes ancestor and all descendants, so `Level Difference` is added to the `TreeClosure`, which is sub-typed as `AllowedCombos` for `LevelDifference in (0,1)`.

- Propagating AK `{PropertyID, PropertyTypeID}`  instead of just `PropertyID`
- Using composite key in `CaseProperty`

---

[image]

---

Here are main constraints from the model to clarify relationships (you may need to modify syntax)

```
ALTER TABLE Property ADD
  CONSTRAINT PK_PR  PRIMARY KEY (PropertyID)

, CONSTRAINT AK1_PR UNIQUE (PropertyID ,PropertyTypeID)

, CONSTRAINT FK1_PR FOREIGN KEY (PropertyTypeID)
         REFERENCES PropertyType(PropertyTypeID)
;



ALTER TABLE TreeClosure ADD
  CONSTRAINT PK_TC PRIMARY KEY (AncestorID ,DescendantID ,AncestorTypeID ,DescendantTypeID)

, CONSTRAINT FK1_TC FOREIGN KEY (AncestorID ,AncestorTypeID) 
             REFERENCES Property(PropertyID ,PropertyTypeID)

, CONSTRAINT FK2_TC FOREIGN KEY (DescendantID ,DescendantTypeID)
             REFERENCES Property(PropertyID   ,PropertyTypeID)
;



ALTER TABLE CaseProperty ADD
  CONSTRAINT PK_CP PRIMARY KEY (CaseID, PropertyID, PropertyTypeID)

, CONSTRAINT FK1_CP FOREIGN KEY (CaseID)
                 REFERENCES Case(CaseID)

, CONSTRAINT FK2_CP FOREIGN KEY (PropertyID ,PropertyTypeID)
             REFERENCES Property(PropertyID ,PropertyTypeID)

, CONSTRAINT FK4_CP FOREIGN KEY (ParentCaseID ,ParentPropertyID ,ParentPropertyTypeID)
         REFERENCES CaseProperty(CaseID       ,PropertyID       ,PropertyTypeID)

, CONSTRAINT FK5_CP FOREIGN KEY (ParentPropertyID ,PropertyID   , ParentPropertyTypeID ,PropertyTypeID) 
        REFERENCES AllowedCombos(AncestorID       ,DescendantID , AncestorTypeID       ,DescendantTypeID)

;
```

Comment: This looks very interesting! I will try it out Monday and report back to see if this answers the question.

Comment: I'm not able to implement all of your solution as it requires changing existing constraints but I can adapt your solution to solve the problem. Thanks!